# Meaning of salutation in terms of job

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-in-context

I am applying for a job in Ernst and Young. On the application there is a question.

***What is your salutation?***

What is the meaning of salutation here? Doing Google searches I found that it means the way we address someone like Mr. , Dear etcetera. But the previous questions in the form are related to my current job.

Kindly help.

Comment: I suspect that it means the title you use in front of your name, Mr, Ms, Doctor, Professor etc - unless it's a mistype for **situation.**

Comment: @Ronald Sole...Can it also mean my position at job? Like web designer, system analyst etcetera.

Comment: It might possibly mean how you should be addressed at the start of correspondence. Are you: Dear Sudhir, Dear Mr Sharma, Dear Dr Sharma, ...?

Comment: It definitely _doesn't_ mean your job title.

Comment: Additionally, it means your life at Ernst and Young will have some downside. Somewhere there is a human resources person who think they know how to create forms. If they meant Mr., Ms., Dr., etc., they should have indicated that near the box for the item. Forms are a hangup of mine. I frequently am required to fill out forms that have aggravations of this kind. If it was on paper instead of on-line, it would undoubtably have provided half the page width for the salutation, but only about a tenth of an inch vertically.